# array php retrieve value

Tags: php, arrays

i have done a module Joomla using php and mysql, one function extract correctly a user on line, then pass the result to another function, that extract an array.

these are the class

```
<?php

class modUno
{

public static function due()
{

$db = JFactory::getDBO();   
$query = "SELECT userid FROM #__session WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'avatar, cb_skipe' FROM #__comprofiler) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
return $result;

}

public static function tre()
{

$risultato = modUno::due();
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT avatar, cb_skipe FROM #__comprofiler WHERE id = '{$risultato}'; ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = array($db->loadResult());
return $result; 

} 
}
?>
```

Then i retrieve the value with these module

```
<?php

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php' );

$foto = ? i dont know ;
$skipe = ? i dont know ;
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_chat');
?>
```

how i can retrieve the value of the array (two value) and assign to $foto and $ skipe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure what you're ultimate goal is, but a couple of things I've noticed which will help are listed below:

1) In modUno::due(); method it appears you are trying to retrieve the user id for the logged in user.  if that is the case, Joomla provides a core method to easily retrieve the currently logged in user object.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$user_id = $user->id;
```

or, if you just need access to the user_id without the entire user object.

```
$user_id = JFactory::getUser()->id;
```

2) When retrieving the values from the modUno::tre(); method, you should use a different method from Joomla's Dbo object to retrieve the result set.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('avatar, cb_skipe');
$query->from($db->quoteName(''));
$query->where('id=' . (int) JFactory::getUser()->id);
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
return $db->returnObject();
```

or

```
return $db->returnAssoc();
```

3) Now you can assign the values like so.

// Call static helper method to load result set.

```
$result = modUno::tre();
```

// If you used loadAssoc()

```
$foto = $result['avatar'];
$skipe = $result['cb_skipe'];
```

// If you used loadObject()

```
$foto = $result->avatar;
$skipe = $result->cb_skipe;
```